# How to Auto Rotate in Window-Based application

Tags: iphone

I was able to auto rate the view based application, but not window based application.  When I google, I do get information for view based application only.

Tnx in advance
Shan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listen for the [`UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification)

then you need to manually manage:

- rotation transform
- view frame
- animation
- status bar
- disabling of user interaction

easiest is to just add a UIViewController and let it do it for you

Comment: Thanks cobbal.. I have converted the project to UIViewcontroller and its working.