# Orientation Problem while using insertSubview

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I get an orientation problem while using the following to code to display a view on top of a split view.

```
[window addSubview:aSplitViewController.view];
[window insertSubview:aViewController.view aboveSubview:aSplitViewController.view];
```

the plain view has a couple of buttons and labels.

So the problem I am facing is that the first view opens in landscape mode but the labels and buttons on the view are in portrait mode.

UPDATE: Here is some code so if anyone wants to see more details...

In my App Delegate

```
- (void) makeSplitViewController {

NSMutableArray *controllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tabBarController.viewControllers];

// First tabbbar item
// detail view
detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navDetailView = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] autorelease];
navDetailView.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;


// root view
rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
rootViewController.detailViewController = detailViewController;
rootViewController.navigationItem.title = @"List";

UINavigationController *navRootView = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController] autorelease];
navRootView.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
navRootView.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
splitViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"Face Sheet";
splitViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gear1.png"];
splitViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Face Sheet";
splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navRootView, navDetailView, nil];
splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
splitViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[controllers addObject:splitViewController];

// Second tabbbar item
scoreViewController = [[ScoreCardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];
scoreViewController.tabBarItem.title = @"Score Card";
scoreViewController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gear1.png"];
scoreViewController.navigationItem.title = @"Score Card";
[controllers addObject:scoreViewController];

tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
```

}

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

// Override point for customization after application launch.
// Create tabbar
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
//tabBarController.delegate = self;

// Set window
[window addSubview:splashController.view];
[window insertSubview:tabBarController.view belowSubview:splashController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

application.statusBarOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;

return YES;
```

}

and here is the code in my SplashScreenView

```
- (IBAction) proceedButtonClick:(id)sender
 {
// Initialize loginpopview
PhysicianLoginViewController *loginViewController = [[PhysicianLoginViewController alloc] init];

popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:loginViewController];
popOverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(350, 200);
popOverController.delegate = self;

// Set a notification to dismiss it later
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(loginViewControllerDone:) name:@"loginViewControllerDone"  object:popOverController.contentViewController];

// Present popover
if ([popOverController isPopoverVisible])
{
    [popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
else 
{

    [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(485, 600, 100, 100) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
}
```

}

```
 // Dismiss popview controller and setup the tabbar
- (void)loginViewControllerDone:(NSNotification *)notification{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

// Button in content view controller was tapped, dismiss popover...
[self.popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

// remove subview
[self.view removeFromSuperview];

// set tabbar
i3EAppDelegate *appDelegate = (i3EAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[appDelegate makeSplitViewController];
```

}

It would be great if someone could point out where I am going wrong. I have been stuck with this problem for quite a few days and I have tried everything that comes to my mind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIWindow` has a subview that it uses for rotations and puts other views inside of that. You need to insert yourself into the root view (or something lower), not the window. Look at `-[UIWindow rootViewController]`.

```
UIView *rootView = [[[self window] rootViewController] view];
[rootView addSubview:view];
```

This will work as long as you're using something with a root view controller. This will work as long as rootViewController isn't `nil`. If you're doing a raw "View Based" application, then it's usually best to pick another view and add your view as its sibling rather than digging through the undocumented hierarchy:

```
UIView *sibling = ... (some other view)
[[sibling superview] addSubview:view];
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.. but I am not exactly sure if that is the solution to my problem.. please correct me if I am wrong... the functionality I am trying to implement is having a splashscreen in the on top of a splitview... when a user enters the correct login, the splash screen disappears and the splitview appears.. this happens correctly in my app.. but the problem is that using the code I typed above, the splashscreen window appears in landscape mode with its components in portrait mode and when the correct login is typed, the splitscreen appears correctly..

Comment: Then the rootViewController option is probably what you want. UIWindow itself never rotates. It has a subview that it transforms. You need to be within that subview, but you should avoid digging randomly through `[window subviews]` to find it. Its implementation is a private detail. Use `rootViewController` instead to find the right place to put your view.

Comment: how do I implement this in my case?

Comment: It is not working.. Even before, I was not rotating the UIWindow.. I am stuck at why this is happening... If I interchange the views as in, if i type [window addSubview:aViewController.view]; and [window insertSubview:aSplitViewController.view aboveSubView:aViewController.view], the view with the buttons and labels is displayed properly in landscape with the buttons and labels in landscape mode as well. However, the splitview now is displayed in landscape with its contents in portrait and is cut at the end...

Comment: Don't call [window addSubview:]. Call [[[window rootViewController] view] addSubview:]. The Window never rotates. It has a subview that it rotates. You're inserting your view beside the rotating view, not inside of it. So the rotating view rotates, and yours does not.

Comment: I am using a window based project and hence the above code does not work for me.. what would I have to change?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend adding a UIViewController (the View-based Application template, or you can add one and wire it to the windows' rootViewController). You can do this all by hand, but it's a pain to do correctly, and you get the problems you're seeing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3137404/how-to-auto-rotate-in-window-based-application

Comment: thats great.. thanks a lot for all that u have said.. last question.. how do I convert to view based from window based?

Comment: Create a new project with a view based template. Depending on the state of your project, you can then either migrate your code into that new project, or use its layout as a guide for how to modify your project. Generally it is easiest to move your code to a new project unless you have a very large project already.