# Converting from a Window based application to a view based application in Ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, templates, view, uiviewcontroller

I would like to know if it is possible for me to convert from a window based application to a view based appln... The reason is because I had already developed a part of my app but am getting some orientation issues which I was told would be solved only by using a view based application.
I was unable to find online any documentation regarding this..

It would be be great if anyone could help me out in this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Window based application" and "view based application" are just two of the templates you can use to start a project, anything you can actually *do* with one you can do with the other.

In the version of XCode I have handy here, the only difference between the two is that "view based" gives you an empty view controller and hooks it up to be displayed on app startup.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. yeah.. i knew that.. but I was wondering if there is a way I could convert from one template to another after I have developed part of my app.. the main reason I was wanting to convert is because of the problem I face, which is there in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585845/orientation-problem-while-using-insertsubview in which at the end of the comments section, he tells me to use a view based template to solve my problem... if you have any insight on how else I can solve that problem, please let me know...

Comment: @learner2010: It sounds like your problem is that UIWindow only handles rotations correctly when it has a single UIView as a subview. You could try adding your view as a subview of `aSplitViewController.view` instead.

Comment: ok thank you... i will look in to it... just to put out an answer to the question I had asked, is it possible to convert a window based template to a view based one? just asking so that I can answer my own question and it could be useful to other ppl who are looking at this same question..

Comment: @learner2010: As I said, the only difference between the two is that "view based" sets up an empty view controller for you. So if you just add a view controller subclass to your project, and then create an instance and add its view as the subview of your UIWindow in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, you've basically done it.

Answer (score 0):

add a view controller subclass to your project, and then create an instance and add its view as the subview of your UIWindow in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:, you've basically done it- anomie
  it's the best and easiest thing you can do as of now