# adding UIButton to window rotation issues

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am doing:

```
UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];
    CGPoint point = CGPointMake(window.frame.size.width/2, window.frame.size.height/2);
    point = CGPointMake(window.frame.size.width - v.frame.size.width - 10, 30);
    point = CGPointMake(point.x + offsetLeft, point.y + offsetTop);
    v.center = point;
    timer1 forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [window addSubview:v];
```

One issue is that when I do in landscape mode:

```
UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:0];
```

and I print:

```
NSLog(@"WINDOW WIDTH IS %f AND HEIGHT IS %f", window.frame.size.width, window.frame.size.height);
```

I got:

```
WINDOW WIDTH IS 768.000000 AND HEIGHT IS 1024.000000
```

Which is not true.. it seems that it doesn't care about orientation.

Comment: @aherlambang what are you expecting?

Comment: it should be rotated 90 degrees from that

Comment: if the view is in portrait then this is correct, but in landscape it should rotate this 90 degrees clockwise from the view I showed above

Comment: @aherlambang isn't it rotated in the picture you've posted?

Comment: those lines behind the gray area is a UITabelView, so just imagine that and I think you'll see what I mean

Comment: @aherlambang I am not sure if your code is related to the problem at hand. Do you use a UIViewController to show the tableView?

Comment: I think it does, as that code is what shows the gray UIView...

Comment: I updated some details to my question above

Comment: @aherlambang Are you using a UIViewController to show your tableView? If not you should, it can easily handle rotation for you. Don't rotate yourself.

Comment: It's actually a UISplitView apps, I am posting the whole view. I updated the view above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not insert views into the `UIWindow`. The `UIWindow` itself does not rotate. It applies transforms to a rotation subview, which holds the root view. You should be inserting your view into the root view if at all possible. Otherwise, you will need to calculate your own transforms, and that's a pain.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585845/orientation-problem-while-using-insertsubview/5585924#5585924) for more details on this issue. The short answer is that this kind of thing is best done by using the View-Based Application template, and making use of the `rootViewController` to get the root view and insert there.

Note that you should also avoid asking for the first window of the `UIApplication`. This is not guaranteed to be the "main" window; the first window is the furthest-back window (and it is not unusual for there to be more than one window). If you must use a `UIWindow`, get it from a view you care about (`[view window]`), or bind it to your `UIApplicationDelegate` in the XIB.

Answer (score 1):

I think only the first subview of your window actually receives rotation events. Try this.

```
[[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] addSubview:SOME_SUBVIEW];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] to get the frame. It will return the appropriate frame information in all orientations. I faced the similar problem. And I dont know the reason for it.

Comment: but how can you add a subview to this?

Comment: After getting proper frame and doing calculations to identify the location of your new adding control or view, add it to window or another view whatever is appropriate for your implementation.

Comment: calculating the frame is fine, the issue is finding the window that I can add to

Answer (score 0):

You can find out which orientation your device is facing with

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
```

Then you could perform a check on it:

```
if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```